# Bar Chart Colour Manipulation in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, colors, bar-chart

I am working with a piece of data in pandas and produced a graph to show the gap in hourly wages between genders.

I first grouped the data into hourly wages by gender using the code

```
`df1 = df[["gender","hourly_wage"]]
staff4=df1.groupby(['gender']).sum()
staff4.head()`
```

then I created a bar plot using the code

```
`my_plot = staff4.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True,title="Gender Pay Gap Analysis")
my_plot.set_xlabel("Gender")
my_plot.set_ylabel("hourly_wage")`
```

and the result I got was the picture below;

[image: Gender pay gap graph]

I intend to make the larger or the second bar have a different colour (say orange). How do I do that?

So far I have tried with `color=[plt.cm.Paired(np.arange(len(df)))])` with no luck.

Also, is itpossible to add a percentage of the bars on top of each bar? to show the percentage wages per gender?

**Problem 2**

The y-axis on the above graph is for hourly wages which ranges from the lowest of `0.53 to 24.98` . How can I format the axis to show a range of 0 - 30 where 1 inch represents £5?

Please any ideas what I can do?

I tried Chris A's suggestion in the comment and it worked

`staff4.T.plot(kind='bar',title="Gender Pay Gap Analysis")`

[image: Transposed Graph plot]

But is it possible to retain the original style of the graph, with the space between the bars? Can I change the orientation of the label on the x-axis?

Comment: Try [transposing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html)... ie `staff4.T.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True,title="Gender Pay Gap Analysis")`

Comment: Thanks @ChrisA I did that and it worked, but it transposed the bar chart into a stacked bar chart. I only want to change the color on the second bar.

Comment: Try taking the `stacked=True` argument out of the `plot` method... `plot` will treat each column of the dataframe as an individual series - each with their own color - so your original grouped dataframe `staff4` only has 1 column, hence only 1 color. Ultimately your goal is to have a column for Male and a column for Female to plot correctly

Comment: @ChrisA Oh I see. Thank you. I edited the original question again. Please can you take a look?

Comment: @ChrisA I tried doing this `staff4=df1.groupby(['gender','hourly_wage']).sum()` for staff4 to create 2 columns and had a `TypeError: no numeric data to plot`

what did I miss?

Comment: I'm not sure `summing` the wages makes sense for this type of analysis...? Have you tried a boxplot? I'd recommend [`seaborn`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/index.html): `import seaborn as sns` then simply `sns.boxplot(data=df, x='gender', y='hourly_wage')` - no groupby or manipulation necessary. This should give a good indication of gender pay gaps and distributions of pay rates

Comment: That's a good point actually. Thank you @ChrisA it looks good.